# Get libraries used in a script in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

Is there any way to get the list of library/dependency files used in a script (for suitescript 1.0 or 2.x API). This is for a client requirement to capture the scripts and dependencies.

I have checked the saved search, but it is not returning the line level files. Please help if there is any way to get this through saved search or scripting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any library files or dependencies used in a script would be listed at the start of the script in the define statement (indeed, they **have to be** listed there).

If you mean is there a way to gather this information for all script files in a NetSuite instance, there is not, to my knowledge, short of examining each script file individually.  If someone has different information, I would be very happy to be proven wrong on this one.

Comment: Hi @Pierre, after doing some research, I got the libraries of the script by loading the relevant script record.